# Specman - Define long var

Tags: specman, e

Can I define a variable as long long as in C in Specman ?
Cant send from Specman uint(bits:64) the gcc is indicating errors.

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't say what the errors are.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 15.1, Specman supports longint/longuint types, 64 bit integers. The int64_t/uint64_t values can be accessed in C using macros:
SN_LONGINT_GET(), SN_LONGUINT_GET(), SN_LONGINT_NEW(int64_t), SN_LONGUINT_NEW(uint64_t)